# Conditional Button-press-event in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, buttonclick, ipywidgets

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will only run a button-click-event if a checkbox is checked.

In more detail, the button-press-event records the mouse click coordinates and plots a vertical red line on the plot at the clicked coordinates. However, I only want this to run if the check box 'On' is checked.

Can anyone help me fix the following code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive

#mouse click function to store coordinates and plot vertical red line
def onclick(event):
    if event == 'On':
        global ix,iy
        ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

        global click_count
        click_count.append((ix,iy))

        #plotting lines where clicks occur
        if len(click_count) > 1:
            ax1.axvline(x=ix, ymin=0, ymax=1, color = "red")

        # assign global variable to access outside of function
        global coords3
        coords3.append((ix, iy))


        # Disconnect after 12 clicks
        if len(coords3) == 12:
            fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
            plt.close(1)
        return

#check box function
def func(label):
    if label == 'On':
        return 'On'

#plots the graph

x = range(0,10)
y = range(0,10)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x,y, color = "blue")
ax1.set_title('This is my graph')

#create the check box
ax2 = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
check_box= CheckButtons(ax2, ('On', 'Off'), (False, False))

#define check box function
check = check_box.on_clicked(func)

# calling out the click coordinates to a variable
coords3 = []
click_count = []


# Call click func
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick(check))

plt.show(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that the following is roughly what this question asks about. There are a lot of problems with the code from the question, I think I cannot comment on all of them, but some major ones are:

- You cannot call the callback function already when registering it. And you cannot simply use some custom argument.  The argument for the matplotlib events are `Event`s.
- You will need to query if the checkbox is being checked or not within the callback function.
- You need to draw the canvas if a new red line is to be shown.
- For a binary state toggle a single checkbox is sufficient. Else it becomes really complicated.
- You will need to check if the click actually happened within the axes. This also requires that the checkbox is not within the axes, else a click on the checkbox would also produce a line.

Complete code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

#mouse click function to store coordinates and plot vertical red line
def onclick(event):
    # Only use event within the axes.
    if not event.inaxes == ax1:
        return
    # Check if Checkbox is "on"
    if check_box.get_status()[0]:

        ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

        coords3.append((ix,iy))

        #plotting lines where clicks occur
        if len(coords3) >= 1:
            ax1.axvline(x=ix, ymin=0, ymax=1, color = "red")
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        # Disconnect after 12 clicks
        if len(coords3) >= 12:
            fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
            plt.close(fig)

#plots the graph
x = range(0,10)
y = range(0,10)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x,y, color = "blue")
ax1.set_title('This is my graph')

#create the check box
ax2 = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
check_box = CheckButtons(ax2, ['On',], [False,])

# List to store coordinates
coords3 = []

# Callback to click func
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()

print(coords3)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! 

Just had to make a minor adjustment to the checkbox code:
    check_box = CheckButtons(ax2, ('On',),(False,))

Comment: What did happen if you left it like it is in the question?

Comment: Threw up this error: 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-cc29dbae214d> in <module>()
     38 #ax3 = plt.axes([0.5, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
     39 
---> 40 check_box = CheckButtons(ax2, ('On',))
     41 
     42 #resetb = Button(ax3, 'Reset', color = 'grey')

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'actives' 
>>>I think it expects you to qualify whether it loads the check box pre-checked or not?

Comment: I see, so indeed in matplotlib < 3.0 you need to supply those.

Comment: Looks like it. Again, thank you so much for this fix - didn't think to query if the checkbox is being checked or not within the callback function!